# I've gotten 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I've coded

```
print("calculate addition. input numbers")

input1 = int(input("the 1st number: "))
input2 = int(input("the 2nd number: "))

print("result: {0} + {1} = {2}".format(input1, input2, input1+input2))
```

but I had the below result.

calculate addition. input numbers

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-2787038f98c1> in <module>()

      1 print("calculate addition. input numbers")
      2 
----> 3 input1 = int(input("the 1st number: "))
      4 input2 = int(input("the 2nd number: "))
      5 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: It seems that you've defined `input = ...` somewhere in your notebook. Try restarting the kernel and removing this assignment if there's any.

Comment: @enzo  it could also be `int`